# How can I make a button go behind a <div> when using display: block?

Tags: html, css, css-float

How to make `<div>` cover a `<button>`? I'm a student now learning `float` in CSS. When making button into block level element I wanted to let button go behind the box, so I added a style on a button, `display: block;`. What I expected was that button goes behind the box, not beside the box. However, it didn't work.

I know how to fix the code to make it happen. But I cannot understand why the code didn't work.

```css
.container {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

button {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <button>click me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: try to use position relative to the box and position absolute to ur button and put top zero and right zero and z-index of -1

Answer (score 0):

your 2 box have float left, they go left 1 after one.
button come after, so on the side

if you put container position relative and button position absolute, it'll take position in container independently of box

you can change value left, right, top bottom for button

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>click me</button>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```